# Why does this webpage display differently when URL forwarded?

Tags: url, forwarding

I have a simple Google maps web application I'm working on.  I have purchased a domain name for the application (http://www.jcunav.com), which during my testing, is designed to simply forward to a page which is hosted on my another domain name of mine (http://www.codeemporium.com/experiments/map5.html).  Testing on my Android Nexus S, I am noticing strange behaviour however - if I visit http://www.codeemporium.com/experiments/map5.html directly, then the app displays as intended - the map is the size I want and clicking the "About" link brings up a dialog the size I want.  If I visit http://www.jcunav.com however (which, keep in mind, simply forwards to http://www.codeemporium.com/experiments/map5.html), the map displays at what looks like a more zoomed out level, and pressing the "About" link at the bottom of the page shows a dialog box which also appears more zoomed out.  My question is, what could be causing this to occur, given that all http://www.jcunav.com is doing is forwarding to http://www.codeemporium.com/experiments/map5.html...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain you aren't frame-forwarding?  I examined the page in firebug for each of the links you provided and it appears to me that you are frame-forwarding the URL.  This results in your target page being 'wrapped' in a frame when presented to the end user.  Odds are high that this is why it is not working for you.

Here is a somewhat lossy version of what is in the forwarded page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>JCU Nav</title>
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</head>
    <frameset frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0" rows="100%,*">
        <frame name="MYTOPFRAME" src="http://www.codeemporium.com/experiments/map5.html" noresize>
        -- snip --

    </frameset>

</html>
```

Notice the frame tag:

```
<frameset frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0" rows="100%,*">
        <frame name="MYTOPFRAME" src="http://www.codeemporium.com/experiments/map5.html" noresize>
```

This is what happens when you frame forward.

Since your sizing relies on additions to the HTML tag:

```
<html class="ui-mobile landscape min-width-320px min-width-480px min-width-768px min-width-1024px">
```

They do not work in the frame-forwarded version because they are nested inside the frame and not on the root page.

Comment: I think you're right.  When I setup forwarding through my domain name registrar, I didn't realise this is how they went about it.

Comment: @BryceThomas, most registrars have several options for forwarding.  Some will call it out with terms like 'Frame" and 'Standard' forwarding.  Others will use terms like 'masked' when referring to frame-forwards.  My guess is you wanted to hide the true URL, but the only way to do that is to use a frame-forward, and I don't think that is going to work for you because of the need to have the class defined on the root HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

That's because http://www.jcunav.com is not forwarding to http://www.codeemporium.com/experiments/map5.html, it is loading it into a frame:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\blah>wget -S -O - http://www.jcunav.com/
--01:05:21--  http://www.jcunav.com/
           => `-'
Resolving www.jcunav.com... 66.150.161.141, 69.25.27.173, 63.251.171.80, ...
Connecting to www.jcunav.com|66.150.161.141|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Sun, 01 May 2011 05:01:11 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.0.49 (Unix) PHP/4.3.9
  X-Powered-By: PHP/4.3.9
  Content-Length: 823
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Length: 823 [text/html]

 0% [                                                                             ] 0             --.--K/s             <
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>JCU Nav</title>
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</head>
        <frameset frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0" rows="100%,*">
            <frame name="MYTOPFRAME" src="http://www.codeemporium.com/experiments/map5.html" noresize>
            <noframes>
                <body>
           <h1>JCU Nav</h1>
           <br>
           <br>
           <br>
           Click here to enter <a href="http://www.codeemporium.com/experiments/map5.html">http://www.codeemporium.com/e
xperiments/map5.html</a>
           <hr>
| Domain Name Registration and Domain Name Forwarding by <a href="http://www.mydomain.com">mydomain.com - Register your
domain name</a>
        </body>
            </noframes>
        </frameset>
</html>
```

You'll need to actually change that frame set to do the right thing.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers so that this could be accepted as well :(